# Proving $\{T(x_n) \}$ converges to $0$.

Tags: functional-analysis

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be normed spaces and $T: X \rightarrow Y$ a linear operator. Prove that if the graph of $T$ is closed then $\{Tx_n \}$ converges to $0$ in $Y$, for all sequences $\{x_n \}$ that converge to $0$ in $X$.

My try:

Since the graph of $T$ denoted by $\mathcal{G}(T)$ is closed we know that the sequence $\{(x_n, y_n)\} \in \mathcal{G}(T)$ converges to $(x,y) \in \mathcal{G}(T) \subset X \times Y$. Since $(x,y) \in \mathcal{G}(T)$, $y = T(x)$ so that 
$$
T(x) = y = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} y_n =  \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty  }T(x_n).
$$
So that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} T(x_n) = T(x),$$ meaning that if $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty } x_n = 0$ we have 
$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} T(x_n) = T(\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(x_n)) = T(0) = 0.
$$

Is this correct? It is like the closedness of the graph implies continuity, which follows from the closed graph theorem in Banach spaces. However, we are now working in normed spaces and not Banach spaces, so I did not use it here.

Comment: Closed does not imply that $(x_n, y_n)$ converges. I am not sure the result you want to prove is true if $X,Y$ are not Banach spaces.

Comment: Your error is in assuming that $(x_n, Tx_n)$ converges to something. The fact that the graph is closed doesn't imply that any sequence there converges, it implies that **if** it converges, it will converge to an element of the form $(x,Tx)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Counterexample: Let $X=C^1([0,1])$, with the norm $||f||=\sup_t|f(t)|$. Let $Y=C([0,1])$, with the same norm. Let $Tf=f'$, the derivative.

Then the graph of $T$ is closed. If $f_n\to f$ uniformly and also $f_n'\to g$ uniformly then it follows that $f$ is continuously differentiable with $f'=g$. But your conclusion fails; $f_n\to0$ uniformly certainly does not imply $f_n'\to0$.

Comment: This is strange.. I took this question from an exam from last year. Maybe they made an error assuming $X$ and $Y$ are normed spaces instead of Banach spaces.

Comment: @Nescrio I've heard that they make mistakes sometimes.

Comment: Haha, unfortunately. Anyways, thanks for the counterexample.